# How can you have two COUNT queries GROUPED BY the same column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two table named, one named Employees, and one named Shop. The Employees table holds the gender of all employees, while the Shop table has the name of the store that each employee works at.

I need to count the number of both male and female employees and group them by the store they work at. For example, the wanted outcome would look like this:

`FemaleEmployees    MaleEmployees    Store
 1                  2               Ed's Hardware
 3                  4               Grocery store`

So far I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Gender) AS FemaleEmployees, StoreName AS Store
FROM Employees 
JOIN Store
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID
Where Gender = 'F'
GROUP BY StoreName;

SELECT COUNT(Gender) AS MaleEmployees, StoreName AS Store
FROM Employees
JOIN Store
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID
Where Gender = 'M'
GROUP BY StoreName;
```

Which obviously gives the needed answer in two select queries, though I need it to be in a single query. I just need help on getting the two into a single query format.

I have experimented with using two subquerys, but so far nothing has worked. I know how to get the answer, just not in the needed format. Would appreciate it if someone could help me figure this one out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As FemaleEmployees,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As MaleEmployees,
       storeName
FROM Employees 
JOIN Store
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID
GROUP BY storeName
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender='F' THEN 1 END) As FemaleEmployees,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 END) As MaleEmployees,
       StoreName AS Store
FROM Employees 
JOIN Store
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID
Where Gender in ( 'F','M' )
GROUP BY StoreName;
```

Filter the `Gender` in `Where` clause to make the query little efficient..

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "case" statement to differentiate between the cases, like this:

`SELECT SUM (SELECT CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MaleCount, SUM (SELECT CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleCount,  Storename AS Store
    FROM Employees
    JOIN Store
    ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID`

```
GROUP BY StoreName;
```

Answer (score 0):

***most of above answer always get count of gender 1 or 0 only...not get actual count..***
**SO GETTING ACTUAL COUNT YOU CAN DO THIS..**

SELECT (CASE WHEN GENDER = 'M' THEN COUNT(GENDER) ELSE 0 END) as MaleCount,
(CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN COUNT(GENDER) ELSE 0 END) AS FemaleCount, 
 Storename AS Store
    FROM Employees
    JOIN Store
    ON Employees.EmployeeID = Store.EmployeeID
GROUP BY StoreName;